# Move canvas pixel by pixel

Tags: gimp

In Gimp, the canvas can be moved by positioning the cursor over the canvas, holding down <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and then moving the cursor.

But, how can I move the canvas by a single pixel?

Comment: Moving the canvas exactly 1 px seems oddly specific. I'm super curious... why?

Comment: Haha, I thought someone would ask.  I screencast while I write in Gimp to create electronic-blackboard-style tutorials.  The 1080p canvas must exactly line up with my 1080p screen.  The canvas can't be larger than 1080p since I export the canvas and use it in the videos also.

Comment: That was my first thought actually. ––– I don't know much about gimp, but I'm thinking that there probably isn't a function that nudges canvas 1px. Maybe there's another way though. I'm not sure how the gui is supposed to be positioned in this setup you have, but in photoshop there is a Fullscreen view mode in which the canvas can be/is centered in the screen.

Comment: Right, I'm also going into fullscreen mode before starting to screencast.  But the canvas is not centered by default, so I have move to the exact position which requires a very steady hand.

Comment: In photoshop it is centered in fullscreen, but if you pan or zoom, you need to center it again. In photoshop you can do that with Ctrl+0 and Ctrl+1 or alternatively with the panning tool, right click document + fit to screen and right click document + 100%. Maybe you can do something similar in gimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GIMP, the most precision I got for panning (positioning the Canvas on Screen) is about 8px - if you click and keep pressed on the pan button at the right of the horizontal scrollbar (which pops up a miniature of the image for navigation ), and then use the arrow keys instead of the mouse cursor.

But according to your comments, maybe centering and fixing in full screen mode is enough - for that, the Zoom option of "fit the image to the window" might fill your needs. The default short cut is `ctrl + shift + J`.

Comment: For me, hitting the pan button, then arrow keys moved the canvas by 20px.

Comment: It seems the ammount of pixels moved actually depends on the zoom factor - in your case, you should loking at zoom 100%, and it is 20px them.

Comment: @garret: what platform are you using? Do you have the possibility of using GIMP unstable (there are nightly builds for Windows). Maybe we could work on this feature.

Comment: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).  Are the nightly builds only for Windows?  I suppose I could also build it from source, but your answer did solve my underlying problem (I probably should have been more direct about my actual problem in the question).